# Azure Cloud Service Remote Debugger not available when publishing from Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Any idea how to enable remote debugging when using Visual Studio Online Hosted Build? When I deploy from visual studio using publish, I'm able to access the Remote Debugger on my Azure Cloud Service. If I publish from Visual Studio Online using the same publish configuration file, I can't use the remote debugger.

The azurePubxml profile has two options `<EnableRemoteDebugger>` and `<RemoteDebuggerConnectorCertificateThumbprint>`, which don't seem to be picked up.